# How can chassis ground be used for voltage measurements in a device with components of differing voltages?

Tags: voltage, voltage-measurement, crt

The manual for my HV probe tells me to connect my ground clip to the chassis. I can see how this would be good advice for say a 12V car, because the chassis is made the ground and every component uses the same power that's hooked to ground.

However this can't be the case with say a CRT circuit. The way I see it, when I want to check voltage of a specific object (a capacitor, let's say) I need to go to the cap with both probes. I don't know if the chassis is "grounded" with a particular voltage (who cares,) but I've got a 24VDC fan motor inside this scope, and a 2,000VDC capacitor. Neither of these components can share a common ground because each is operating at a different voltage. If I wire the ground wire of a 30VDC LED and the ground wire from a 200VDC motor to a sheet of aluminum and turn it on, things are going to spark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Things at different voltages often share the same ground.

When you say "If I wire the ground wire of a 30VDC LED and the ground wire from a 200VDC motor to a sheet of aluminum and turn it on, things are going to spark." you are making an assumption that is not necessarily true.  This is where you are getting off track: "Neither of these components can share a common ground because each is operating at a different voltage"

Ground can be the same for all kinds of voltages in the same system, the same way the ground itself can be used as a point of reference when measuring different peoples' heights.

Remember, ground isn't a voltage, it is simply a reference point against which other potentials are weighed.

Comment: take the people's height measurement a bit further and think of measuring the heights of a group of people that are standing on multiple steps of a stairway

Answer (score 1):

Not everything is "grounded" to chassis.  It is normal, allowable *and often necessary* to have a circuit entirely floating from "ground".

> Take the electrical controls and accessory loads on a subway train or light rail.  You have two separate systems: 600V-3000V line voltage, which propels the car. And 24-72V battery voltage, which runs controls, lighting and smaller accessories.  These cars are able to run in multi-car trains, and they have conductive wires between them carrying the control voltage. The line voltage system MUST be "chassis ground" because the rails are the current return. One of the cars runs up on rusty rail.  Its motors are trying return 400A of current from the third rail to the car's chassis to the rails, but its wheels have no contact with the rails.  How does the current flow? Well, if the battery controls are chassis grounded, it will try to cross the "ground" wire in the inter-car plugs.  Those things are maybe 10 AWG (4mm<sup>2</sup>).  So FOOF goes the wire, and now you have 600V running around in all the control circuits, frying stuff and shocking passengers. *Not good.*

The same thing may well apply to an HV circuit, for instance one energizing a magnetron or luminiscent display.

Another example is the secondary of a transformer that you are bridge rectifying and tying the DC- to ground.  If you try to tie the transformer secondary to ground also, then you have a short circuit.

The obvious fallacy is the belief that there is a ground, or an "aether", which is a universal reference voltage for all things.  That's not true. There are safety wins by creating isolation - so the first "ground fault" between the isolated system and chassis is harmless.

So sometimes, hooking a voltage tester to "ground" is the wrong thing to do.